# Continuous packaging with buildr

Tags: tomcat, buildr

Apache buildr offers continuous compilation. JSPs, however, can only be served in tomcat. The first idea is to run `buildr package` and copy the war into tomact. As deployment in tomcat takes some time, I copy the `target` directory directly into a separate directory. That directory is manually enrichted by the libs required by the project.

The issue now is that I have to trigger `buildr package` always manually. `buildr compile` is not enough as the content of `webapp` is not regarded. I put my JSPs in `webapp`. After an update of an JSP, buildr should trigger `buildr package`. I am aware that this is more than I need, but I can hook into some webapp task to do my copying stuff.

Therefore, Is there something similar to `buildr cc`? `builder cp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such task.

You shouldn't need to package your war every time, you can point Tomcat to the target folder, granted that it contains the WEB-INF folder. You would need to redeploy the app on Tomcat anyway, but it would be less painful.

Yet another option is to run with Jetty, which is provided as a buildr add-on, and/or use tests for your JSPs.